# Import data tier application in Managed instance

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am using SSMS 18.0 Preview 6 and wanted to import the .bacpac file we have locally stored and accessible. However, seems the function is not supported in the GUI . Any updates/suggestions are welcome.

We will use the sqlpackage.exe, hoever wanted to know if GUI supports this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From SSMS v18.0 RC1 we can use GUI to import bacpac into Managed instance. Just tested it and it went fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [SqlPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-2017) instead:

```
sqlpackage.exe /Action:Import /tsn:MyServer /tdn:worldwide /tu:MyUserName /tp:MySecretPwd /sf:c:\sql\WideWorldImporters-Standard.bacpac
```

The command will import the bacpac file to Azure. The parameters used are the following:

/Action is used to indicate if we are going to import, export, publish, and extract data.

/tsn is used to define the Target Server Name.

/tdn is the name of the new database to be created.

/tu is the Target User. It is the Server Admin Login.

/tp is the Target Password. It is the password defined.

/sf is the source file.